# How to call a contract from pallet with specific interface

Tags: ink, pallet

I'm trying to use Ink as a programmable hook for my pallet.

TD;LR;

My pallet will store `Agreement`.

```rust
struct Agreement<T> {
  // ...
  pub on_approve: T::AccountId // this point to an Ink contract
}
```

and there is a call

```rust
#[pallet::call_index(1)]
#[pallet::weight(0{})]
pub fn approve(origin: OriginFor<T>, aggrement_id: u32) {
  let origin = ensure_signed(origin)?;
  let mut agreement = Agreement::<T>::get(aggrement_id)?;

  agreement.approve();
  // TODO: call agreement.on_success

  OK(())
}
```

I can call an Ink contract via `pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call()`.
However, I want to ensure the contract must conform to a specific interface.

for example

```
#[ink::trait_definition]
pub trait MyPalletHook {
    #[ink(message)]
    fn on_success(&mut self, agreement: Agreement);
}
```

Is my idea reasonable?
Can pre-check a smart contract code or deployed instance implement a specific trait? How to call the contract via function definition in the trait?